# Process exited in a forever loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

```
con = redis.StrictRedis()
def consumer():
    logger.debug("ca   ")

    while True:
        print(111)`enter code here`
        # logger.debug(queue_key)
        message = con.brpop(queue_key)
        print(f'processing {message}')
    
        params = message.split(',')
        coro = callback(*params)
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)

def multi_consumer():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(3)
    logger.debug("start multi process")
    for i in range(1):
        r = executor.submit(consumer)
```

callback is an async func defined with async (not important)

```
from consumer import multi_consumer
from multiprocessing import Process


p = Process(target=multi_consumer, daemon=True)
p.start()
```

result :
the program exited at once.

I want to know why this will happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly is happening? The while loop is exiting by itself and you don't want that? Or is it something else?

Comment: `for i in range(1)` is no forever loop, it is executed once.

Comment: sorry I cannot let you clear at once. The while loop is exiting by itself and I do don't want it happen

Comment: I found my mistakes. the redis connnect return a tuple of (key, value) and I process it as a normal string which causes the exception that stop the world~~~